# email script for multiple receiver

Tags: javascript, email

I stuck sending mails to email script for multiple receiver
May someone could help me

```
var recipient2=(ss.getSheetByName("ECA-Points & Personal Nr.").getRange("T16").getValue()) + ',' + (ss.getSheetByName("ECA-Points & Personal Nr.").getRange("T25").getValue()) + ',' + (ss.getSheetByName("ECA-Points & Personal Nr.").getRange("T28").getValue()) ;
```

it should send to 3 different mails which could change.

Any help is welcome

This is my complete code, I try to work with cc and bcc but it always send the mail only to one email

```
    // Define your variables here
function mailPDFtoHO( optSSId, optSheetId ) {
//If a sheet ID was provided, open that sheet, otherwise assume script is
//sheet-bound, and open the active spreadsheet.
var ss = (optSSId) ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(optSSId) : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//Get URL of spreadsheet, and remove the trailing 'edit'
var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
//Get folder containing spreadsheet, for later export
var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
if (parents.hasNext()) {
var folder = parents.next();
}
else {
folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
}
//Get array of all sheets in spreadsheet
// var sheets = ss.getSheets();
//Loop through all sheets, generating PDF files.
//for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {
//var sheet = sheets[i];
//If provided a optSheetId, only save it.
//if (optSheetId && optSheetId !== sheet.getSheetId()) continue; 
//additional parameters for exporting the sheet as a pdf
var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
//+ '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId()   //the sheet's Id
//following parameters are optional...
+ '&size=A4'      //paper size
+ '&portrait=false'    //orientation, false for landscape
+ '&fitw=true'        //fit to width, false for actual size
+ '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
+ '&gridlines=false'  //hide gridlines
+ '&fzr=false'      //do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
+ '&gid=1672240374'
+ '&ir=false'  //seems to be always false
+ '&ic=false'   //same as ic
+ '&r1=1'     //Start Row number - 1, so row 1 would be 0 , row 15 wold be 14
+ '&c1=0'       //Start Column number - 1, so column 1 would be 0, column 8 would be 7   
+ '&r2=78'      //End Row number
+ '&c2=29';       //End Column number;
var options = {
headers: {
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
}
}
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, options);
var blob = response.getBlob().setName(ss.getName() + '_' + ss.getSheetByName("Timesheet").getRange("B5").getValue() + "_" + ss.getSheetByName("Timesheet").getRange("X5").getValue() + "_" + ss.getSheetByName("ECA-Points & Personal Nr.").getRange("T7").getValue() + "." + ss.getSheetByName("ECA-Points & Personal Nr.").getRange("T5").getValue() + '.pdf');
//from here you should be able to use and manipulate the blob to send and email or create a file per usual.
//In this example, I save the pdf to drive

var recipient1=Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var recipient2=ss.getSheetByName("ECA-Points & Personal Nr.").getRange("T16").getValue() ;
var recipient3=ss.getSheetByName("ECA-Points & Personal Nr.").getRange("T25").getValue() ;
var recipient4=ss.getSheetByName("ECA-Points & Personal Nr.").getRange("T28").getValue() ;
var subject1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + ' ' + ss.getSheetByName("Timesheet").getRange("B5").getValue() + ' ' + ss.getSheetByName("Timesheet").getRange("X5").getValue() + " " + ss.getSheetByName("ECA-Points & Personal Nr.").getRange("T7").getValue() + "/" + ss.getSheetByName("ECA-Points & Personal Nr.").getRange("T5").getValue() ;
var subject2='FW:' + '  ' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + ' ' + ss.getSheetByName("Timesheet").getRange("B5").getValue() + ' ' + ss.getSheetByName("Timesheet").getRange("X5").getValue() + " " + ss.getSheetByName("ECA-Points & Personal Nr.").getRange("T7").getValue() + "/" + ss.getSheetByName("ECA-Points & Personal Nr.").getRange("T5").getValue() ;
var body="Hello " + ss.getSheetByName("ECA-Points & Personal Nr.").getRange("T13").getValue() + "," + "\n\nPlease find attached the timesheet for " + ss.getSheetByName("Timesheet").getRange("X5").getValue() + ".\n\nBest Regards,\n\n" + ss.getSheetByName("ECA-Points & Personal Nr.").getRange("T10").getValue();




 var message1 = {
    to: recipient1,
    subject: subject1,
    body: body,
    attachments: [blob]
  }



 
 var message2 = {
    to: recipient2,
    cc: recipient3,
    bcc: recipient4,
    subject: subject2,
    body: body,
    attachments: [blob]
  }

var confirm1 = Browser.msgBox('send confirmation','Are you sure you want to send this mail to your mail-box?', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if(confirm1=='ok'){ MailApp.sendEmail(message2)};


var confirm2 = Browser.msgBox('send confirmation','Are you sure you want to send this mail to your Bundget Resposible ' + ss.getSheetByName("ECA-Points & Personal Nr.").getRange("T19").getValue() + ' , time agent ' + ss.getSheetByName("ECA-Points & Personal Nr.").getRange("T22").getValue() + ' and DAOS?', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if(confirm2=='ok'){ MailApp.sendEmail(message1)};
```

Comment: it only send the mail to the value get from 'T16' but not the rest

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Also, can you add a tag for the language you are coding in?

Comment: Sorry I am a newbie,